# Application Match error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Application.Match to get the row number of a value, and to fill a form with all data of the row. It works perfect when sought value is alphanumeric, but error 13 is returned if sought value is numeric. Why?

Error occurs on line `ultimafila = Application.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0) + 2`

```
Private Sub textoCodigo_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Double, j As Double, C As Range, ultimafila As Variant ', ultimafila As Double
Set ws = Worksheets("Identificación"): Set ws2 = Worksheets("lista_riesgos")
Set C = ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Find(textoCodigo.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Trim(Me.textoCodigo.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
    Me.textoCodigo = Null
    Me.textoTipo = Null
    Me.textoResponsable = Null
    Me.textoDescripcion = Null
    Me.txtDetalle = Null
    Me.textoControles = Null
    Me.textoFrecuencia = Null
    Me.textoEscala = Null
    Me.textoImpacto = Null
    For j = 0 To listaObjetivos.ListCount - 1
        listaObjetivos.Selected(j) = False
    Next
    Exit Sub
End If

ultimafila = Application.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0) + 2

If Trim(Me.textoCodigo.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If
index = C.Row
textoCodigo.Value = UCase(textoCodigo.Value)
Me.alertaCodigo.Visible = False

Me.textoTipo = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.Range("Riesgos[Tipo]"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
Me.textoResponsable = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.Range("Riesgos[Responsable]"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
Me.textoDescripcion = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
Me.txtDetalle = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))

If Trim(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").DataBodyRange.Cells(ultimafila - 2, 25).Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
    Me.textoControles = Null
    Me.textoFrecuencia = Null
    Me.textoEscala = Null
    Me.textoImpacto = Null
Else
    Me.textoControles = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(21).DataBodyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
    Me.textoFrecuencia = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(22).DataBodyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
    Me.textoEscala = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(23).DataBodyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
    Me.textoImpacto = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(24).DataBodyRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.Range("Riesgos[Cod.]"), 0))
End If

For j = 0 To listaObjetivos.ListCount - 1
    listaObjetivos.Selected(j) = False
Next

For i = 0 To listaObjetivos.ListCount - 1
    If ws.Cells(index, (i) + 6) = "X" Then
        listaObjetivos.Selected(i) = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: the period `.` after `Cod` does not look right

Comment: I've tried with `ultimafila = Application.Match(Me.textoCodigo.Value, ws.ListObjects("Riesgos").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0) + 2`, but I got same error 13 with numeric values of `textoCodigo`

Comment: Try testing the return value from `Application.Match()` using `IsError()` before trying to use it.  If there's no match then you cannot add 2 to the return value...

Comment: Using `IsError()` returns `false` if looked up value is alphanumeric, and returns `true` if looked up value is numeric. Both values I want to find exist in the range